# how to export "=test" string value into excel using Vba

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

Hi Im working on ms access 2013 and im trying to export data into the excel.when the string is "=test 1" it throws Application defined or object defined error. can someone let me know how to handle this error

Comment: Put an apostrophe in front of the text.

Comment: Thank you for the response.How to add it for recordset fieldvalue

Comment: Prepend it using `"'"&[Field name]` in your query.

Comment: Thanks a lot..It Helps!!!